# java.lang.NullPointerException in onResume()

Tags: android

After minimizing my app by pressing the home button and reopen it after 5-10min I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.cwalz.betconnection.aq.a(Unknown Source)
at com.a.a.a.k.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The only time I overwrite onResume() is in my Base Activity, which my other activities extend from:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 9000).show();   
    }
}
```

I can't figure out where the problem is (the exception is not that useful..).

EDIT: I was able to deobfuscate the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.cwalz.betconnection.WelcomeActivity$3.onSuccess(Unknown Source)
at com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

WelcomeActivity.java

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    // views
    static ListView followingView;
    static ListView betView;

    // values
    static List<Bet> betList = new ArrayList<Bet>();
    static List<Bet> followingList = new ArrayList<Bet>();

    // adapter
    static BetListViewAdapter betAdapter;
    static BetListViewAdapter followingAdapter;

    // fragments
    FollowListFragment followFragment;
    BetListFragment betFragment;

    // drawer values
    protected List<String> mMenuItems;
    protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    protected ListView mDrawerList;
    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    protected CharSequence mTitle;
    protected CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
     * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    /**
     * The current user
     */ 
    UserHandler user = null;



    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        // create user object
        user = new UserHandler(getApplicationContext());

        if (!user.isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
        }

        // set ad for non premium user
        if (!user.isPremium()) {
            AdHandler.setBannerAd(this, (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adPlaceholder));
        }

        // check if bet was submitted
        String bet = "";
        bet = getIntent().getStringExtra(AddBetActivity.EXTRA_BET);
        if (bet != null) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

        // check if first login
        Boolean firstLogin = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(RegisterActivity.EXTRA_FIRSTLOGIN, false);
        if (firstLogin) {
            showFirstLoginDialog();
        }

        // ...

        // show progress bars
        loadData();

    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                betFragment = BetListFragment.getInstance();
                return betFragment;
            }
            else {
                followFragment = FollowListFragment.getInstance();
                return followFragment;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            if (position == 0)
                return getString(R.string.page_title_bets);
            else
                return getString(R.string.page_title_following);
        }
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    // ...

    public static class BetListFragment extends Fragment {
        Context context;
        View rootView;
        ListView listView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        TextView noBets;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            context = container.getContext();
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bet_list, container, false);

            listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.betList);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            noBets = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.noBets);

            betAdapter = new BetListViewAdapter(context, R.layout.listview_bet, betList);
            listView.setAdapter(betAdapter);
            // set listener
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Bet bet = betAdapter.getItem(position);

                    Intent betActivity = new Intent(context, BetActivity.class);
                    betActivity.putExtra("de.cwalz.bet.BETID", bet.getID());
                    startActivity(betActivity);
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }

        public View getRootView() {
            return rootView;
        }

        public void showLoadingView(boolean status) {       
            if (status) {
                listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                noBets.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
            }
        }

        public BetListFragment() {}

        public static BetListFragment getInstance() {
            return new BetListFragment();
        }
    }

    public static class FollowListFragment extends Fragment {
        Context context;
        View rootView;
        ListView listView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        TextView noFollowingUsers;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            context = container.getContext();

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bet_list, container, false);
            listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.betList);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            noFollowingUsers = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.noFollowingUsers);

            followingAdapter = new BetListViewAdapter(context, R.layout.listview_bet, followingList);
            listView.setAdapter(followingAdapter);
            // set listener
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Bet bet = followingAdapter.getItem(position);

                    Intent betActivity = new Intent(context, BetActivity.class);
                    betActivity.putExtra("de.cwalz.bet.BETID", bet.getID());
                    startActivity(betActivity);
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }

        public View getRootView() {
            return rootView;
        }

        public void showLoadingView(boolean status) {
            if (status) {
                listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                noFollowingUsers.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
            }
        }

        public FollowListFragment() {}

        public static FollowListFragment getInstance() {
            return new FollowListFragment();
        }
    }

    private void loadData() {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

        String email = user.getEmail();
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", user.getPassword());
        params.put("token", TextUtil.getToken(email));

        DataUtil.post("GetBetList", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    // hide progress bars
                    betFragment.showLoadingView(false);
                    followFragment.showLoadingView(false);


                    JSONArray blist = response.getJSONArray("blist");
                    JSONArray flist = response.getJSONArray("flist");

                    // add bets
                    betList.clear();
                    for(int i=0; i<blist.length(); i++) {
                        // ...
                    }

                    // add bets from followed users
                    followingList.clear();
                    for(int i=0; i<flist.length(); i++) {
                        // ...
                    }

                    if (betList.isEmpty()) {
                        TextView text = (TextView) betFragment.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.noBets);
                        text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if (followingList.isEmpty()) {
                        TextView text = (TextView) followFragment.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.noFollowingUsers);
                        text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    // notify adapter and show listview
                    betAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    followingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                     Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });         
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using ProGuard by any chance? Because that would explain why your exception is not that useful.

Comment: Can you put a break point here and debug and see on what line, the exception is thrown?

Comment: How do you know it is inside onResume()? Maybe the activity was recreated and onCreate() was called.

Comment: @Schoentoon Yes I'm using ProGuard. brummfondel that was just an assumption.

Comment: Might need to check for null with `if (status != null && status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { ... }`

Comment: @ChuongPham int can't be null. I'm trying to reproduce the issue, but it's currently not crashing..

Comment: @Chris as you're using proguard either recompile without proguard and cause the same crash and post that stacktrace. Or deobfuscate this stacktrace, otherwise it is basically worthless.

Comment: @Schoentoon I was able to obfuscate the exception. Please see my edit.

Comment: You still aren't managing to de-obfuscate the internal class to find the actual line number.  But an alternative approach is to just log every object you use in the onSuccess method, and then you'll be able to see which one is null and fix whatever pathway got it there.  Likely when you app resumes things start off in a way that skips the creation or initialization of some object, therefore you crash because it is null.

Comment: How to de-obfuscate the line number? I was using this tutorial: http://blog.simplyadvanced.net/android-how-to-decode-proguards-obfuscated-code-from-stack-trace/